# Convert float[] to android.graphics.Matrix

Tags: android, rotational-matrices

I am developing an android application and I need to convert a float array of 9 elements into an object of type android.graphics.Matrix. The float array represents a rotation matrix returned by SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(...). I want to use this float array converting it in an android.graphics.Matrix to use in canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint).

How can I set the values of the float array to the Matrix object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the Android documentation:

[`setValues`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setValues%28float%5B%5D%29)